# The "non-man" explanation of -n in echo (shell)

Tags: bash, shell

So i read the `man echo` info. And it says this for the `n` option.

```
-n    Do not print the trailing newline character.
```

I can't wrap my head around what it means.

So if i try it out this is what i get

```
~ echo -n "12"
12%
```

I get a `%` after the argument I passed in.

Without `n`, stdout will not have `%`

```
~ echo "12"
12
```

Can anyone give practical examples, or a simpler explanation.

Comment: Is `%` your prompt character?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if you mean it's what I see in the terminal then yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard invocation of the `echo` command will print out the argument passed to `echo`, followed by a newline character.

Invoking `echo` with the `-n` flag will just print out the argument, without the newline character.

Because you use `%` as the prompt character in your shell, invoking `echo -n "12"`, will print out `12`, immediately followed by the prompt character to indicate that the shell is ready to accept new input.

It would look like this without `-n`:

```
% echo "12"
12
%
```

And with `-n`:

```
% echo -n "12"
12%
```

Comment: wotd - prompt character. Nicely explained.